# How to manage multiple user in single android app?

Tags: android

I am working on android project, in which I have to maintain multiple user logged in at a time. App should have switch logged in users facility.

And at the same time all logged in user must receive their firebase notification. and each user session should maintain.

I have maintain session for single user, as shown in this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/) by using Shared Preferences.

Now I am not getting how to maintain session for multiple user with switch user option in android app.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I am not getting how to maintain session for multiple user with switch user option in android app.

You handle it the same way you are handing the single user, with the only distinction of having them distinguishable, usually by assigning unique local id and having all data (incl. FCM tokens, API access tokens etc) referenced by that ID.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean that maintain session using Shared Preferences.

Comment: How you store is actually pretty much irrelevant. Shared prefs will work as well.